# Swift - return array with NSURLSession

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to return an array with my NSURLSession call.

I have the following method:

```
func wsQAshowTag(tag: Int) -> AnyObject
    {
        var tableArray = []

        let requestString = NSString(format:"URL", tag) as String
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(NSURL(string: requestString)!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            do{
                tableArray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! NSArray
                print(tableArray)
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }
        })
        task.resume()
        return tableArray
    }
```

When I call this method and try to print it, its empty. When I put breakpoints inside my method, I can see that tableArray is getting populated....why is it doing this and how do I fix it?

```
let wsQAshowTagArray = self.wsQAshowTag(38936)
        print(wsQAshowTagArray)
```

Comment: can you post the JSON response?